# MFT driver for Metro interface

Tags: windows, com, video-streaming, microsoft-metro, driver

In my app I use an Avstream driver for video splitting.  The driver works well, but there is one problem with apps workings under Metro interface  (MS Edge and IE). Those apps saw the driver but didn't wish connect to it.

By Google I found that Metro did lock IKsControl interface. I used  it for  link with my COM plugin. So I see two solutions for Metro here:

1. Remove IKsControl and replace it by ReadFile/WriteFile operations
2. Or use MFT driver ([enter link description here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/dn394064%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)).  That driver is used for connect a camera driver and Metro interface.

I would like to try  the second variant - to add that MFT driver between my Avstream driver and Metro.  What do you think about it?

Answer (score 0):

Bad solution. MFT driver can use if your own driver is supported by Metro.  It only adds some capture features to your driver.